# How can i setup Drush to use a proxy server to access internet on Windows7?

Tags: drupal, windows-7, proxy, wamp, drush

i am using WAMP for Drupal development. I have installed drush and it works fine when using home network without any proxy. When i am at work, the network setting uses a proxy to access internet and hence any drush command which need internet, eg. drush dl {module_name}, doesn't work.

After googling i could only find texts that told me how to configure them on *nix based OS. I'm stuck with windows7. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I got it running. I had to do the following change to make drush dl work on windows 7. Apparently "which wget" wasnt returning anything as windows doesn't have a 'which' command. I hacked the drush core to do the following changes.

1. Go to file drush.inc in folder C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes
2. Change the line $use_wget = drush_shell_exec('which wget'); with $use_wget = drush_shell_exec('where wget');

Root Cause:Windows doesn’t have 'which' command, 'where' command serves the purpose

I think there was no issue with proxy at all and it was using proxy from drupal's settings.php file correctly

Comment: If drush isn’t able to download anything from internet try to fix proxy by adding this line in the wgetrc file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\GnuWin32\etc folder.

`http_proxy = http://proxy.server.name:port_number`

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193654/how-to-use-drush-with-proxy